# How do I refactor three database operations that only differ by the method call?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, refactoring, transactions

I have three database operations like so:

```
public void Add<T>(T entity)
{
    using (var transaction = Session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        if (entity is IEnumerable)
        {
            foreach (var item in (IEnumerable) entity)
            {
                Session.Save(item);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Session.Save(entity);
        }

        transaction.Commit();
    }
}

public void Update<T>(T entity)
{
    using (var transaction = Session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        if (entity is IEnumerable)
        {
            foreach (var item in (IEnumerable) entity)
            {
                Session.Update(item);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Session.Update(entity);
        }

        transaction.Commit();
    }
}

public void Delete<T>(T entity)
{
    using (var transaction = Session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        if (entity is IEnumerable)
        {
            foreach (var item in (IEnumerable)entity)
            {
                Session.Delete(item);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Session.Delete(entity);
        }

        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

As you can see, the only thing that differs is the `Session.[something]` part. How would I refactor this into only one method?

Comment: Why do you use separate transactions? Isn't it wrong to write (possible) different data than you read?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The transactions get committed after each operation, so the read should get up-to-date data.

Comment: I mean you don't read (something like session.get) inside the same transaction as you write (something like session.save). You can have phantom reads or overwrite with stale data. The whole database operation should be in one transaction, not just a part of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delegates look like a good solution here, as explained by other answerers.  One other possible refactoring that could arguably simplify the inside logic would be a function that returns an IEnumerable.  If the passed-in object is an IEnumerable, just return it; otherwise build a single-element enumeration with the passed-in object and return the enumeration.  This would turn this:

```
if (entity is IEnumerable)
{
    foreach (var item in (IEnumerable) entity)
    {
       Session.Save(item);
    }
}
else
{
    Session.Save(entity);
}
```

into this:

```
foreach (var item in ForceEnumerable(entity))
    {
       Session.Save(item);
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, that's an interesting approach!

Answer (score 0):

You can make one method, and have it accept a delegate as a parameter, that specifies the action you want to do.

```
private void DatabaseAction<T>(T entity, Action<T> action) 
{
    using (var transaction = Session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        if (entity is IEnumerable)
        {
            foreach (var item in (IEnumerable) entity)
            {
                action(item);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            action(item);
        }

        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

Then refactor your 3 methods to:

```
public void Add<T>(T entity)
{
    DatabaseAction(entity, item => Session.Save(item));
}

public void Update<T>(T entity)
{
    DatabaseAction(entity, item => Session.Update(item));
}

public void Delete<T>(T entity)
{
    DatabaseAction(entity, item => Session.Delete(item));
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile (cannot convert item from object to T).

Comment: That is because your foreach loop works on objects. If the Session.Xxx methods is meant to work on any object, change Action&lt;T&gt; to Action&lt;object&gt;. If the entity being passed in should contain T instances, then change your code so you enumerate on the generic version of IEnumerable.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass in an [Action<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) that should be performed for the entity:

```
public static void DoInTransaction<T>(this T entity, Action<T> action)
{
    using (var transaction = Session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        if (entity is IEnumerable<T>)
        {
            foreach (T item in (IEnumerable<T>) entity)
            {
                action(item);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            action(entity);
        }

        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

Example:

```
entity.DoInTransaction(Session.Save);
entity.DoInTransaction(Session.Update);
entity.DoInTransaction(Session.Delete);
```

Comment: Hellfrost, can you elaborate?